# Difference between qemu-kvm, qemu-system-x86_64, qemu-x86_64

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu

For new features, I recently updated qemu-kvm 1.5.3 to qemu 2.5.0, but I saw several qemu binaries, `/usr/local/bin/qemu-x86_64` and `/usr/local/bin/qemu-system-x86_64`. It seems `qemu-system-x86_64` is the emulator program, since libvirt won't recognize `qemu-x86_64`. Then what's qemu-x86_64 for?

And according to [this qemu doc](http://wiki.qemu.org/KVM):

> qemu-kvm fork for x86 (deprecated, use upstream QEMU now)

It seems qemu is replacing qemu-kvm. But if qemu not qemu-kvm is used, is the guest CPU still provided by KVM? If not so, will the performance be worse?

Comment: On what Linux distribution?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Linux 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 CentOS 7.1

Comment: @MichaelHampton qemu-kvm is not even located in /usr/bin, it's located in /usr/libexec and is binary: /usr/libexec/qemu-kvm: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, stripped

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I asked the mailing list, here's what I got:

- qemu-arch like `/usr/local/bin/qemu-x86_64` is for running a program of that arch on the host machine of what ever arch, but not a virtual machine
- qemu-system-arch like `/usr/local/bin/qemu-system-x86_64` is for running a system of that arch on the host machine
- to enable kvm support, qemu parameter `-enable-kvm` is needed, libvirt should have taken care of this if right xml is configured

Thanks Jakob for the answer in the [mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/qemu-discuss/2016-04/msg00013.html).

Comment: Does qemu not automatically detect that you're on the same architecture between host and guest and use kvm automatically?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai I'm not sure about this, but likely not, see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/QEMU#Enabling_KVM